# Error opening Xcode 4.5 project on Xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I was using using Xcode 4.5 to create an iPad application yesterday and completed it. But today when I took that same Xcode project and tried to run it on an older machine running Xcode 4.2, it is giving me an error about IBNSLayoutConstraint. Which i guess was due to the new features that were included in the new Xcode 4.5. So I was thinking is there a way to open project from new Xcode in the older version without having to install a new Xcode and OSX.

[image: two muppets]

I am not sure if this question is asked here yet or not, but i tried to find a solution but no luck in that either.

PS. I already know that the best solution is to not opent those projects in older version but that is not what i am looking for.

Comment: The solution is to _not_ open newer projects in older Xcode versions.

Comment: I was thinking of a better solution that this one as i already know it.

Comment: One thing you could try is to turn on autolayouts for each XIB. Not sure if that will work though. Honestly you should just use the newer version, or if you really can't, then create a new project in the older version and copy stuff over (except for the XIBS) and then recreate the XIBS by hand.

Comment: What OS does the *older machine* run?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an option in the inspector window when you select the xib file that will not use the constrains under "Show file the inspector" in the inspector called "Use autolayout".

Here is a screen shot of it.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

uncheck autolayout feature from each xib file the open your project on xcode4.2, it works on my case, as autolayout is only available in iOS6